# Trying to find out whether my advisor is ignoring me

Tags: thesis, advisor

So the story is something like this:

Week-1: My advisor meets me. We have a chat. Then he explains me about his time management style. I said okay.

Week-2: No email replies to anything.

Week-3: I make all pdf's ready, presentations ready, keeping in view of time management. The advisor meets me this time is very delighted of the preparations and says to keep it up. He is also pleased with the work I have done.

Week-4: No email replies to anything.

Week-5: I get to know another parallel group had a meeting and I get a reply back that he is busy with some personal things. He also told maybe he can meet tomorrow.

I am getting a feeling that my advisor is trying to ignore me and I don't have guts to go ask them directly. Is my advisor really ignoring me? I am confused. And thanks in advance for answering the question.

Comment: Maybe just busy. You probably aren't his only responsibility.

Comment: Had a lecturer that was tough and unapproachable in our first year... but by halfway through the second year he was different as if you got that far you showed some promise so worthy of his effort. A tough stance, but with a large intake in the first year and a large dropout rate understandable. The final year - his door was open at all times whether you needs 5 minutes or an hour - lectures took priority though.

Comment: From my experience, you need to think about incentives not intentions when it come to people in academia. Your advisor incentive is to do their work first. One can say, that it should be their good intention to help, but that is rare. In conclusion, dont rely on advisor too much. Listen to him/her, but otherwise the responsibility is up to you. I know this may sound harsh, but dont worry, academia is not that complicated and after few trial/errors, you will be good  to progress on your own.

Comment: I doubt that he's ignoring you, he's just busy. My best advice is not to take it personally because you never know what's going on in someone's life...